# Value of $ \sum_{t \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}} \zeta ^{Tr (t)} $

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/p } $. Then is it true that $ \sum_{t \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}} \zeta ^{Tr (t)} = 0  $, where $Tr$ is the map $ Tr:\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p}$ defined by $Tr(a) = a+a^p+a^{p^2}+......a^{p^{n-1}}$? If so, why? I know that $Tr$ is onto.

Comment: This is a standard fact. Many ways to see it. Let $S$ be your sum and $a\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ a fixed element such that $Tr(a)\neq0$. Then $t$ ranges over the field as $t+a$ does, so
$$S=\sum_{t}\zeta^{Tr(t+a)}=\zeta^{Tr(a)} S,$$ leaving $S=0$ as the only possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at $$\sum_{l=1}^{p-1} \sum_{t \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}} \zeta^{l\ Tr (t)}$$
Equivalently show that since $Tr$ is a surjective group homomorphism then $|Tr^{-1}(t)| = p^{n-1}$.